# Manual markers for code folding in RubyMine

Tags: ruby, rubymine

In RubyMine, is it possible to insert manual fold markers (like vim or emacs)?

I want to automatically fold a very large hash whenever I open a file. It's available in [IntelliJ](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/03/custom-code-folding-regions-in-intellij-idea-111/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Rubymine has the same function like IntelliJ.

Select any code region you like, press <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on a mac or some other similar keys binding on windows (I haven't a win install right now).  Also you can do this from menu: `Code` -> `Surround With...`.

To go to any custom folding, press <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> on mac, or from menu: `Navigate` -> `Custom Folding...`.

Comment: That's great, thank you!! I mustn't had the code highlighted, therefore the command didn't appear in the menubar. I'm new to visual editors, I've been using vim since before the Wright brothers.

Comment: Actually I have "Surround with" option inactive for feature files. However, everything is ok with .rb
Any ideas what should I change?