# Rubymine: Code folding: "Surround with" is inactive for *.feature files

Tags: ruby, rubymine, gherkin, folding, code-folding

I wanted to created a custom folding region (like  it's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46901353/manual-markers-for-code-folding-in-rubymine)), however "Surround with" is inactive for *.feature files.
It's enabled for *.rb (but still no custom folding option in the menu). 
For *.rb files I successfully use #region #endregion, but what about feature files? Any options to have the same #regions?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment it's not supported in RubyMine so others who'd like to see this option implemented might refer to the request you've submitted: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-24080